# Getting error : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send while running powershell script

Tags: powershell, api, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

```
$API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx"

# Source image files
$ImageFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg\* -filter *).Name

$uploadedFiles = @()

try {
foreach ($imageFile in $ImageFiles ) {
    # 1a. RETRIEVE THE PRESIGNED URL TO UPLOAD THE FILE.
   
    # Prepare URL for `Get Presigned URL` API call
    $query = "https://api.pdf.co/v1/file/upload/get-presigned-url? 
contenttype=application/octet-stream&name=" + `
        [IO.Path]::GetFileName($imageFile)
    $query = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($query)

    # Execute request
    $jsonResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY } -Uri 
$query

    if ($jsonResponse.error -eq $false) {
        # Get URL to use for the file upload
        $uploadUrl = $jsonResponse.presignedUrl
        # Get URL of uploaded file to use with later API calls
        $uploadedFileUrl = $jsonResponse.url

        # 1b. UPLOAD THE FILE TO CLOUD.

        $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Put -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY; "content-type" 
  = "application/octet-stream" } -InFile $imageFile -Uri $uploadUrl
       
        if ($r.StatusCode -eq 200) {
            # Keep uploaded file URL
            $uploadedFiles += $uploadedFileUrl
        }
        else {
            # Display request error status
            Write-Host $r.StatusCode + " " + $r.StatusDescription
        }
        }
    else {
        # Display service reported error
        Write-Host $jsonResponse.message
    }
    }

    if ($uploadedFiles.length -gt 0) {
    # 2. CREATE PDF DOCUMENT FROM UPLOADED IMAGE FILES

    # Prepare URL for `DOC To PDF` API call
    $query = "https://api.pdf.co/v1/pdf/convert/from/image"

    # Prepare request body (will be auto-converted to JSON by Invoke-RestMethod)
    # See documentation: https://apidocs.pdf.co
    $body = @{
        "name" = $(Split-Path $DestinationFile -Leaf)
        "url" = $uploadedFiles -join ","
    } | ConvertTo-Json
   
    # Execute request
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY; "Content- 
 Type" = "application/json" } -Body $body -Uri $query
   
    $jsonResponse = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
   
    if ($jsonResponse.error -eq $false) {
        # Get URL of generated PDF file
        $resultFileUrl = $jsonResponse.url;

       

        $DestinationFile = "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\pdf\$imagefile.split('.')[0]"
       
        # Download PDF file
        Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY } -OutFile $DestinationFile -Uri 
   $resultFileUrl

        Write-Host "Generated PDF file saved as `"$($DestinationFile)`" file."
    }
    else {
        # Display service reported error
        Write-Host $jsonResponse.message
    }  
    }
     }
   catch {
# Display request error
Write-Host $_.Exception
  }
```

Basically this script converts bulk number of JPEG images to PDF format .Its working initially but later when i execute the script it is getting failed by this error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." . I googled this issue and added these two lines at the beginning of the script –
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocolNet.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 .
Even after adding these two am getting the same old error .Can anyone please help me with this issue

Comment: If the error were related to TLS, the second half of the error message would read "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

Comment: Am not frequently getting this error .If i execute this script for 10 times 2 times am getting this error